# iOS - UIImagePickerController to display images from a specific Album only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, alassetslibrary

I'm currently using `ALAssetsLibrary` to save my images into a custom album using `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

```
[self.assetsLibrary addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:album
                                      resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
                                          NSLog(@"added album:%@", album);
                                      }
                                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"error adding album");
                                     }];


__block ALAssetsGroup* groupToAddTo;
        [self.assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                                    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                        if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:album]) {
                                            NSLog(@"found album %@", album);
                                            groupToAddTo = group;
                                        }
                                    }
                                  failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                      NSLog(@"failed to enumerate albums:\nError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                  }];


CGImageRef img = [imageToSave CGImage];
        [self.assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:img
                                          metadata:metadata
                                   completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {
                                       if (error.code == 0) {
                                           NSLog(@"saved image completed:\nurl: %@", assetURL);

                                           // try to get the asset
                                           [self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:assetURL
                                                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                                             // assign the photo to the album
                                                             [groupToAddTo addAsset:asset];
                                                             NSLog(@"Added %@ to %@", [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename], album);
                                                         }
                                                        failureBlock:^(NSError* error) {
                                                            NSLog(@"failed to retrieve image asset:\nError: %@ ", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                        }];
                                       }
                                       else {
                                           NSLog(@"saved image failed.\nerror code %li\n%@", (long)error.code, [error localizedDescription]);
                                       }
                                   }];
```

I would like to have my `UIImagePickerController` to select images from the custom album ONLY, or a way to select only images saved by my app. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `AlAssetLibrary` to populate your own version of the `UIImagePckerController` and filter out only the images you want (those in the album name you want). [Here is a sample code by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135) that demonstrates this

Comment: Did Lefteris example link work for you Gudmund? I'm looking to do the same thing. Thanks. It's such a shame Apple doesn't let us simply change the source of the picker to the custom album.

Comment: The image picker worked, but I couldn't get it to filter out images based on albums.